# Modelling many to many relationships in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2, meteor-collections, nosql

Hi I am building a small app to get used to Meteor (and Mongo). Something that is bothering me is the data modelling aspect. Specifically what is the best way to model a many to many relationship. I have read in the Mongo docs that a doc should not be embedded in another doc if you expect it to grow while the original doc remains fairly static. 
In my test app students can register for courses. So from the Mongo perspective it makes sense to include the students as an embedded doc in the course as each course will have a  limited number of students as opposed to the other way round where, over time, a student could theoretically join unlimited courses.

Then there is the Meteor aspect, I read that a lot of Meteor's features are aimed at separate collections, such as DDP working at the document level so any change in the student array would cause the entire course doc to be resent to every browser, and things like the each spacebars helper works with Mongo cursors but not with arrays etc, etc.

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation and could they explain what approach they took and any drawbacks they had to deal with etc? Thanks.

Comment: I think this type of discussion is more suitable for the Meteor forums.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publishing-relations

The Meteor team tames (or hides!) the javascript monster to an amazing extent. By using their conventions, you get "free" a ton of much-used functionality "out of the box".  Things that are usually re-invented over and over again, accounts, OAuth, live data across clients, standard live-data protocol etc.

But very soon... you need features not in the box.  Wow... look at all the choices.  Wait a minute, this is the same monster you were fighting before Meteor!

So use the official Meteor Guide.  They recommend the wisest ways to extend functionality of your app when you make these choices.

Since they know how they have "hidden the monster", they know how to keep avoiding the monster when you extend.